# Is there a way to build snap or a linux app without using snapcraft?

Tags: linux, flutter, snapcraft, appimage

I'm using flutter dev and I wanted to enable linux support to many applications and followed this [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/linux) but the thing is

Everytime I try to run `snapcraft` launches a VM and installs flutter again from the snap

this uses lot of my disk space,time and internet `snapcraft --use-lxd` does the same

So is there any other way to build a linux app either a deb file, appimage or anything is fine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is conflating two different steps: building an application, and packaging an application. To build a Linux application with Flutter all you need to do is run `flutter build`, and you'll get a release mode Linux application.

How you package it for distribution is to you; nothing about Flutter requires snaps as the distribution option. For instance, you could just zip up the contents of the `bundle` folder in the build output directory, and post that somewhere for people to download.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti My answer has nothing to do with snap, so you seem to have posted your comment in the wrong location. The question asked was whether it's possible to build a Flutter app for Linux without using snapcraft. My answer is explaining that it is. I cannot "install a hello world app to the snap store using this method [I] describe" because what my answer is describing is **not using snap**.

Comment: Maybe the title changed while you were away.  "Is there a way to build snap or a linux app without using snapcraft?"
Once I have a snap, installing to the snapstore is easy.  I have done so with another app made with electron-builder.
I guess you were speaking in the context of non release builds.  Flutter run will do the trick to have a desktop run on linux.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti The title hasn't changed; "or a Linux app" is a key part of that title. See also the actual question: "So is there any other way to build a linux app either **a deb file, appimage or anything** is fine?" I was not speak ing in the context of non-release builds, no. I explicitly said how to build a release build in my answer. If you want to ask a question that is only about building a snap, you should post a new question to the site asking that instead of complaining that my answer to **a different question** doesn't tell you how to make a snap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be used to make a desktop app for windows mac and linux

https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/hover

Comment: Note that that's a completely different embedding with its own set of feature and bugs, separate plugin ecosystem, etc. It's not just different tooling for Flutter's desktop support.